# Coversion of ArrayList to an Array of Specific Type

Tags: java

Below code convert Array List to array and store result as type object.How can I convert it into a specific type like array of Strings.

```
   List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
 list.add("Blobbo");
 list.add("Cracked");
 list.add("Dumbo");
 Object[] ol = list.toArray();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this:

```
String[] ol = list.toArray(new String[0]);
```

Comment: You did see that the question is flaged as a duplicate?

Comment: Ooh yes, I have seen it. ^^